# Need subdomain for my website whenever user creates his account

Tags: java, templates, web, subdomain

I have my own website [www.example.com] developed in SpringBoot, whenever the user logged in to my system, it should changed to [www.username.example.com]. what need to configure whenever user created his account?

Comment: You need to create a DNS record

Comment: Thanks Malt,please add more points. Am very new to this